# how to extract elementary stream from transport stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, transport, dvb-t

i have .ts file looks like the following

```html
Input #0, mpegts, from 'i.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:36.32, start: 28752.398067, bitrate: 57694 kb/s
  Program 50 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : aaa HD
      service_provider: 
    Stream #0:51[0x1f5]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:52[0x1f6]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels, fltp
  Program 51 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : b Music HD
      service_provider: 
    Stream #0:16[0x1ff]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:17[0x200]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels, fltp
  Program 52 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : c ch HD
      service_provider: 
    Stream #0:14[0x209]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:15[0x20a]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels, fltp
  Program 1510 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : asd
      service_provider: xyz
    Stream #0:18[0x5e7]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:19[0x5e8]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels, fltp
```

i need to extract one video stream and its audio stream from this file for example related to program 50 i tried

```css
ffmpeg -i i.ts -map 0:51 output.mp4
```

but i got this error

```css
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:51 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:51 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Share full log of failing command.

Comment: the question is updated with the log

Comment: Full log, please. Upload it to pastebin..etc if it is too large.

Comment: this is the full log
https://pastebin.com/Yas609Mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/stoyanovgeorge/ffmpeg/wiki/How-to-Map-Streams-in-FFMPEG)

For mapping the whole programs, the syntax is:

```
ffmpeg -i i.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:p:51 output.mp4
```

I can't verify that solution is actually working with your `.ts` file.

I created the following sample, that builds a `.ts` file with two programs, and then extracts each program to `.mp4` file:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i testsrc=rate=10:size=160x120 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -t 5 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac in1.mp4
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=rate=10:size=160x120 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=300 -t 5 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac in2.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i in1.mp4 -i in2.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -map 1:1 -program title=ProgOne:st=0:st=1 -program title=ProgTwo:st=2:st=3 -c:v copy -c:a copy in.ts
ffmpeg -y -i in.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:p:1 output1.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i in.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:p:2 output2.mp4
```

- 1st command builds video test pattern with high frequency beep (output: `in1.mp4`).
- 2nd command builds video Mandelbrot pattern with low frequency beep (output: `in2.mp4`).
- 3rd command builds transport stream with two programs (output: `in.ts`).
- 4th command extracts first program (output: `output1.mp4`).
- 5th command extracts second program (output: `output2.mp4`).

Comment: the command give me this error 
[mp4 @ 0x7fc3fc01be00] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:16 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:17 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times

Comment: Can you check if program 51 is playable using [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/)?